# git rebase branch with grandparent

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I am reading about `git rebase` and  was reading through - [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#More-Interesting-Rebases)'s documentation.

I have a specific doubt about using the `onto` feature of git rebase to rebase a branch to its grandparent (just like the case in above link).
Let us assume we have a branch/commit structure like the following:

```
C1 <- C2 <- C5 <- C6 [master]
         <- C3 <- C4 <- C10 [server]
               <- C8 <- C9 [client]
```

Now, I want to rebase `client` brnach onto `master`. I checked out `client` branch and ran `git rebase --onto master server client` command. The resultant structure I got (after merging and fast-forwarding master to client) from this command is:

```
C1 <- C2 <- C5 <- C6 <- C8' <- C9' [master, client]
         <- C3 <- C4 <- C10 [server]
```

My doubt is, what if my changes in `client` branch were depending on C3 commit in `server` branch. The resultant code in `master` branch would certainly fail in such a scenario as rebase does . As far as my knowledge goes, shouldn't the actual result (after merging and fast-forwarding master to client) be like:

```
 C1 <- C2 <- C5 <- C6 <- C3' <- C8' <- C9' [master, client]
                             <- C4 <- C10 [server]
```

Can somebody please let me know whether my understanding/concern is wrong?

Comment: 1.  You mislabeled the second diagram.  `master` should be `client`.  2.  In the third diagram (also mislabeled) why would you expect `server` to change?  You're only rebasing `client` after all.

Comment: @jcm For second diagram I assumed fast forwarding of `master`. For third diagram, yes, even I was confused myself about changing the `server` branch, but how else can this be done (commtting C3 to master) if not by changing `server`.

Comment: There is no fast-forward of master unless you did `git checkout master` `git merge client` after the rebase operation.  The answer to your original question is "The rebase won't go through, it will stop with a mess of merge conflicts unless you also grab C3"

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, I just skipped/assumed those steps to keep the question short. About rebase not going through, I am afraid that is not the case, rebase just take commits from `client` branch and proceeds. The actual problem was that I mentioned `wrong upstream` as pointed out in  jthill's answer.

Comment: Skipping/assuming steps is a good way to get confused answers and your questions downvoted.  The rebase should only proceed if there weren't dependencies.

Comment: @AndrewC Point noted, thanks! But, I still didn't get how would rebase stop. Let us say commit C3 adds a new object 'Cache' which will be used by both server and client. Now in commits C8 & C9, I am using this object, so there is a dependency of C8 on C3, but rebase would still proceed, leaving the base object class 'Cache' in server branch and committing C8 and C9 alone in client branch.

Comment: Are you saying you tried this and it worked?  When I do `(client)$ git rebase --onto master HEAD~1` I get `Failed to merge in the changes. Patch failed at 0001 ` and a lot more error output that stops the rebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My doubt is, what if my changes in client branch were depending on C3 commit in server branch. The resultant code in master branch would certainly fail in such a scenario as rebase does

That's right.  You've explicitly sliced commit C3 out of your rebased history.  Why do that?  Just `git rebase master client`.  When you merge `server` git won't try to apply the C3 changes again because they won't show up in the diffs (or alternately further changes to those lines will conflict).

edit: comoits aren't "on" branches.  The history matters.  The branch names are just lightweight ("throwaway" wouldn't be such a bad word here) references to help identify the commits that interest you.  Focus on the commtts themselves and their ancestry.

Comment: Thanks that worked!
So, server side of history remains unchanged, and it will align itself when I run rebase on server (after fast forwarding master of course) and will skip the changes already committed upstream. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you start from

```
C1---C2---C5---C6  master
       \
        C3---C4---C10  server
          \
           C8---C9  client
```

and you expect the result to be

```
C1---C2---C5---C6---C3'---C8'---C9' master, client
                      \
                       C4---C10  server
```

Then the misunderstanding is:  ***C3'* cannot be the ancestor of *C4***.  That cannot happen here.

When you do

```
git rebase --onto master server client
```

and, as you put it, changes in *client* "depend" on changes from *C3*, you can resolve the merge and you'll get

```
C1---C2---C5---C6  master
       \         \
        \         C8'---C9' client
         \
          C3---C4---C10  server
```

Now, after you merge *master* and *client*, and you are ready to rebase *server*, two scenarios could happen:

#### 1. If you kept the changes from *C8* that "depend" on *C3* in the previous conflict, after you resolve the current conflict git will say

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'? If there is nothing left
>   to stage, **chances are that something else already introduced the same
>   changes; you might want to skip this patch**.
>
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue". If
>   you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead. To
>   check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase
>   --abort".

You can then do

```
git rebase --skip
```

and you'll get

```
C1---C2---C5---C6---C8'---C9'  master, client  
                             \         
                              C4'---C10' server
```

Notice there is no *C3'* as those changes were applied with *C8'*.

#### 2. If you did not keep the changes from *C8* that "depend" on *C3* in the previous conflict, after you resolve the current conflict and do

```
git rebase --continue
```

you'll get

```
C1---C2---C5---C6---C8'---C9'  master, client
                             \         
                              C3'---C4'---C10' server
```

Which means that when there are changes on `<branch>` "depending" on `<upstream>` that conflict with `<newbase>` when rebasing, git provides you the merge resolution mechanism as a way to choose if you want those changes now or later.

Comment: Let's say I am not yet ready to rebase server to my master branch. I need to merge (I use rebase for a linear history) client's code with master branch. But this would fail because commit `C3` isn't there and my commits to `client` branch (C8 and C9) depend on it.

Comment: Just for clarification in the above comment, merge would succeed, but the resultant code would fail.

Comment: The commit *object* for C3 is not there, however you can resolve the conflict so as to include the *required changes* from C3 to have the resultant code work.  This feature exists in case you are not ready to integrate all the changes from C3 and only want the changes required for the *client* branch.  Otherwise you could just do `git rebase master client`.